# At what value of p are you indifferent between action A and action B?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bayesian, decision-theory

Problem statement: Suppose you are deciding between two actions, A, and B, and are testing between two mutually exclusive hypotheses, H1 and H2. If you choose action A, you receive 1 dollar if H1 is true and nothing if it is false.  If you choose action B, you receive 2 dollars if H1 is true and lose 1 dollar if it is false. Suppose H1 is true with posterior probability p.

Question: At what value of p are you indifferent between action A and action B?

I understand the problem statement but i don't understand the question and I have no idea where I should start? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "Indifferent" means the values you assign to the two actions are equal.  Thus, you begin by specifying how you will determine the value of an action.  Then you compute and compare those values.  *This question therefore has multiple, subjective answers,* because they depend on how *you* assess an action's value.  Differences in valuation are often attributed to difference levels of *risk averseness.*

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yeah, this is my homework problem. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @GioiHocSinh If this is your homework, why don't you post what you've tried thus far.  You mention you have no idea where to start, but your notes must mention something. Show us what you've tried and we can help you from here. Additionally, please add the `self-study` tag to your question.

Comment: @DemetriPananos I think I added self_study tag already. I also mentioned that I understand the problem statement but I don't understand the question and I have no idea where I should start.

Comment: @whuber I thought that we already had the action values? There are 4 actions: A|H1, B|H1, A|H2 and B|H2 with the values are 1, 2, 0 and -1 respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this problem in terms of *utility*.  Let $U(x \vert \theta)$ be the utility under a given action, $x=A, B$ and state of the world/hypothesis $\theta = H_1, H_2$.

Because there are two possible hypotheses and 2 actions, we can enumerate our utilities

$$ U(A \vert H_1) = 1 $$

$$ U(A \vert H_2) = 0 $$

$$ U(B \vert H_1) = 2 $$

$$ U(B \vert H_1) = -1 $$

We are also given the information about the posterior probability of one of the hypotheses, $P(H_1) = p$.  Since the hypotheses are mutually exclusive, $P(H_2) = 1-P(H_1)$. Using this information, we can compute the expected utility for each action, with I will denote $E(U(x))$.

$$E(U(A)) = U(A\vert H_1)P(H_1) + U(A \vert H_2)P(H_2) = p$$

$$E(U(B)) = U(B\vert H_1)P(H_1) + U(B \vert H_2)P(H_2) = 2p - (1-p) = 3p-1$$

You're indifferent to the decision when each decision has the same expected utility.  So solve $3p-1=p$ or $p=0.5$.  This makes sense, when there is an equal chance of either hypothesis being true then both actions have the same expected pay off (namely a dollar).

Comment: What you receive is the *gain* (negative of a loss), not the "utility."  The latter could be different.